# Rails acts_as_votable gem ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I new in Rails framework. I used `acts_as_votable` gem and `will_paginate` gem. When I wanna `order` the `articles` by `upvote`  but it doesn't work. I used acts_as_votable's `get_likes` method for order but I failed. I'm really stuck.

Article Model:

```
default_scope  { order(get_likes: :desc) }
```

after that I get `Statementİnvalid error`.

Comment: get_likes is a method and it can't be used as you are trying, as it is considered as a column in that table

Comment: let me write it for you

Answer (score 4):

Your `get_likes`- method will not work with an order-scope, because the sort order is executed on the database and your method's data is unknown to the database.

You could sort your records in ruby, using array methods, but that is slow and this operation should be done at database level.

By using counter-caches which store the number of counts for a record in a column you can sort in the database. The acts_as_votable gem already offers [counter-cache implementations](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#caching).

You just need to add the migration of the column you need to the database. Here the coulmn from their docs:

```
add_column :posts, :cached_votes_total, :integer, :default => 0
```

Afterwards you can sort with the order scope.

```
Post.order(:cached_votes_total=> :desc)
```